# How to override the tomcat home page

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to override the tomcat home page, as I need index.html as the home page rather than the index.jsp.

So I tried to set in the web.xml as follows:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

When I restart the tomcat, It still go to the index.jsp page.

PS: I am using the Intellij 13, is it the case?

Answer (score 3):

Short anwser: if what you want is to "override" the default context, you need to install your webapp in the directory "ROOT" inside webapps.